# wicket DataTable getSort state does not change

Tags: dependency-injection, wicket

Thank you for you're attention, I've got this weird problem I'm not able to solve. I've build a DataTable with wicket mapped with content from mongoDB. Also I'm working with Tomcat7 and Eclipse

However each time I select a column to sort then the getSort() method in the iterator method of the data provider always returns me the same value that is the default one.

```
public SortableGalaxyDataProvider() {

    setSort("name", SortOrder.ASCENDING);
}

@Override
public Iterator<? extends Galaxy> iterator(long first, long count) {

    SortParam<String> sort = getSort(); //is always the same
```

initialisation of my page is done this way

[Edit] I'm using Spring for injection, so in GalaxyTable page I have.

```
@Inject
SortableGalaxyDataProvider galaxyProvider;

public GalaxyTable() {

    List<IColumn<Galaxy, String>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Galaxy, String>>();

    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Name"),"name","name"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Type"),"type","type"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Ancestors"),"ancestors","ancestors"));
    columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Radius"),"radius","radius"));


    add(new DefaultDataTable<Galaxy, String>("galaxies", columns, galaxyProvider, 10));
}
```

Here is the html line used for the table

```
<wicket:extend>
<table cellspacing="0" wicket:id="galaxies">[table]</table>
</wicket:extend>
```

I looked for many examples around and no one seems to get the same trouble, the initial display is normal and I can travel through the content however it will never get sorted cause sort state is not changing.

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code looks good, could you provide a quickstart showing the problem ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that :). The code is relatively simple and there isn't much more than what I showed. I added some additional info in the first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of fixing Spring injection problem :

Injecting the DAO into the page and using it in the constructor of the data provider works.

```
    @Inject
    //SortableGalaxyDataProvider galaxyProvider;
    UniversDAO dao;

    public GalaxyTable() {

        List<IColumn<Galaxy, String>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Galaxy, String>>();

        columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Name"),"name","name"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Type"),"type","type"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Ancestors"),"ancestors","ancestors"));
        columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Galaxy,String>(new Model<String>("Radius"),"radius","radius"));


        //add(new DefaultDataTable<Galaxy, String>("galaxies", columns, galaxyProvider, 10));
        add(new DefaultDataTable<Galaxy, String>("galaxies", columns, new SortableGalaxyDataProvider(dao), 10));
    }
```

However I'd rather like it to work with regular spring injection. The problem, as Cedric said, might be this wrapper spring put on.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be caused by the use of a SpringBean. The way it work, I think there is a autogenerated Proxy put in the injection point, thus, when Wicket tries to set the sort state using introspection, it does it in the proxy (or fails to do it). Another thing that could happen is that Spring recreates the GalaxyProvider bean between two ajax requests, the sort state would also be lost.

I would try to get rid of injection in your code and see what it do.

Comment: I think it might be the answer. I'm looking for the break point when Wicket actually tries to set the sort state in order to confirm or infirm this.

Comment: The project is now using Play Fwk, this question won't go further.